# Tableau table filter for one column only in table

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field

I have a really basic question that I can't figure out. I need to create a table that has multiple calculated fields, but I need only one of the calculated fields to be filtered for a specific dimension value. For example, I have the following data set (dummy data) and I want to create a table that will include total clicks for both companies, but [cost per click] from one company only, company B.

DATA SET

```
Company| Clicks| $ Cost
------------------------
Comp A | 100   | $20
Comp B | 200   | $40
```

WHAT I'M LOOKING FOR

```
       CLICKS | COST/CLICK
TOTAL   300   |  $0.13
```

$0.13 comes from 40/300; $40 from company B and 300 clicks from both company A and B.

How do you create a table that has multiple calculations but with one of those calculations filtered on one dimension value only?

Comment: Does each company record have its own line (row), or is all of the company data on a single row?

Comment: Each company has its own row, so for example, clicks, cost, etc are in one row for company A and then clicks, cost, etc are on a second row for company B. Is this what you mean? The post I wrote had the dummy data chart formatted correctly, but it looks like it wasn't formatted correctly when it was posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple calculated field:

```
sum(if [Company] = 'B' then [Cost] end )/sum([Click])
```

Comment: That won't work if the data is partitioned in any way (if you have the company field on the report, the SUM function will only add the clicks for that group. http://imgur.com/1kPHVML, and you still cannot filter out company A, because if you filter out company A, then tableau won't add those clicks.

Comment: True but OP didn't mention his table structure.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much! I don't need to show the breakout by company, just the total, so I think that's why it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you in the right direction.
Based on your question and your comment, **you want to divide the cost by the TOTAL number of clicks in your dataset.**

1. Create a calculated field called "TotalClicks" and enter this formula
   `window_sum(sum([Clicks]))` // This formula will sum the clicks field for all rows
2. Create a calculated field called Cost / Clicks and enter this formula
   `sum([Cost]) / [TotalClicks]` 
   Add the Cost / Clicks field to the sheet and it should look like this

NOTE: If you need to partition / group your report, you may have to play around with this some. I don't use window functions within tableau very often since I usually handle the aggregation at the datasource level instead.

[image]

NOTE: Since you mentioned filtering, I will add this statement -- If you filter out any of your data, that data will not (cannot) be included in any calculated fields (To the best of my knowledge and experience, anyway). If you need to include that data (total clicks), I **think** the only option is to add that aggregated total to your dataset - otherwise, tableau can't calculate it if you are filtering it out.

Edit2: If you cannot change the underlying dataset, you could accomplish this by creating another datasource and joining it to your inital data source --

1. Data > Add Datasource, add the datasource again and change the name so you can identify it
2. Click Data > Edit Relationships. Click Custom and REMOVE any linked fields -- this will essentially produce a Cartesian join (every record in your first DataSource will have every reocrd from your second Datasource)
3. Select the second datasource and create a calculated field (ClicksTotal_DS2) using the same window_sum function
4. Select the first datasource and create a calculated field (named Cost / Clicks_DS2) using this formula 
   `sum([Cost])/ [Sheet1 (test) (2)].[ClicksTotal_DS2]`

Now you can apply a filter to your first data source, and your second data source will still calculate the total.
[image]

Comment: Thanks Aron! The formula above worked. But thanks for your explanation. It will be useful in another project I'm working on.